# How to align button and ul elements horizontally

Tags: css

I want to achieve following layout:

[my button][hello1][hello2]

This is html:

```
<div id='container'>

  <button id='my-button'>my button</button>
  <ul id='my-ul'>

    <li>hello1</li>
    <li>hello2</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

How to define css?

Comment: It's not exactly the same question as asked in 'Horizontal list items', which is ul only. Does button align with ul > li? This is why this question is asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `display: inline-block;` along with removing the padding on the `ul` element. Also, I have added a `container` class to the div to avoid using IDs in CSS.

```css
.container > button, .container > ul, .container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' class="container">

  <button id='my-button'>my button</button>
  <ul id='my-ul'>

    <li>hello1</li>
    <li>hello2</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the right way to this.
In this case, you want to align every element in the container element, and the elements in the list, so the css should be

```
.container {
  display: flex;
 }

  ul {
   display: flex;
  }
```